# Retrieve a Blob by ID/Name from Google Blobstore

Tags: google-app-engine, blobstore, google-cloud-datastore

Storing images in Blobstore is working really well especially because of the `serving url` which doesn't require any frontend instances.

```
ServingUrlOptions options = ServingUrlOptions.Builder.withBlobKey(blobKey);
String url = imagesService.getServingUrl(options);
```

After uploading the images I throw away the filenames (it is auto generated). Blobs in the datastore console have the kind `__GsFileInfo__` and have the fields as follows:

```
Key: agljbHV0dHJ3ZWJyY...
Write Ops: 10
ID/Name: encoded_gs_key:L2dzL2NsdXR0ci81MDkxZmFlMC1iMGVhLTQxNzctYmU...
content_type: application/octet-stream
creation: Fri May 08 15:13:26 CDT 2015
filename: /gs/bucket1234/5091fae0-b0ea-4177-be46-36cc7df5a36c
```

I noticed that the serving url is the same as `ID/Name` - which my only handle to the blob/image. Is there a way to `get` the blob by `ID/Name`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to retrieve the blob by itd blobkey just use:

```
 BlobKey blobKey = new BlobKey(req.getParameter("blob-key"));
 blobstoreService.serve(blobKey, res);
```

Comment: thanks. i used the ID/Name to construct the `BlobKey` but the service could not find it. since i didn't need to `serve` it i just tried to delete it and got `Could not delete blob: <BlobKey: encoded_gs_key:L2dzL2NsdXR0ci81YTJkOGMwNy0xMWQyLTRiOWYtOGFlZC1jOGNjOGMyMDMwNzU>`